# How to conditionally include XAML ResourceDictionary in Xamarin.Forms projects using .csproj MSBuild

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, msbuild, visual-studio-mac

We use a single branch of code to build multiple versions of iOS and Android apps. We use conditional MSBuild commands in the platform specific projects which works well. There is also some conditionally styles in XAML (colors and styles) which we would like to conditionally use based on build configuration.

I'm trying to conditionally include a ResourceDictionary in a Xamarin.Forms (5.0) project depending on the build configuration in Visual Studio Mac 2019 using the following.

```
<None Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug-Brand1'" Include="Brands\Brand1\Colors.xaml">
    <Link>Colors.xaml</Link>
</None>
```

Brands/Brand1/Colors.xaml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ResourceDictionary
        xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

             <!-- Colors -->
          <Color x:Key="PrimaryColor">#ffffff</Color> 
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

I then try and use the ResourceDictionary in App.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Colors.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

[Error message of Resource "Colors.xaml" not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKXF8.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the path of `Colors.xaml`.

Change:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Colors.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

To:

```
 <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Brands/Brand1/Colors.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Update:**

It's also valid to place all resources between **explicit** ResourceDictionary tags. Since Xamarin.Forms 3.0 the ResourceDictionary tags are not required. Instead, the ResourceDictionary object is created automatically, and you can insert the resources directly between the Resources property-element tags.

```
 <Application.Resources>

    <!-- Colors -->
    <Color x:Key="AppBackgroundColor">AliceBlue</Color>
    <Color x:Key="NavigationBarColor">#1976D2</Color>
    <Color x:Key="NavigationBarTextColor">White</Color>
    <Color x:Key="NormalTextColor">Black</Color>

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MyColors.xaml" />
          
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I can't use the explicit path - I have multiple folders e.g. Brand1, Brand2, Brand3 and multiple build configurations e.g. Debug-Brand1, Debug-Brand2, Debug-Brand3 etc. I want to conditionally include the correct Colors.xaml and merge the resourcedictionary into the App.xaml.

Comment: For my test, only the absolute path works. I sugggest to use the absolute path.

Comment: Any update for this case? If this reply helps you, please accept as answer. Thanks~

Comment: I can't use an absolute path, we want to conditionally include a file (as a a link) based on build configuration. The code I provided works if the 'Condition' attribute is removed i.e. the linked resourcedictionary Color.xaml is merged in.

Comment: How about set the colors in `Resources` directly? Check mu update.